# Hypothesis Testing (Exponential Distribution)

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, density-function, exponential-distribution, confidence-interval

Let $X$ have the probability density function $f(x;a) = \frac{1}{a}e^{-x/a}, 0 < x < \infty$;
$\Omega = \{a; a = 2,4\}$

To test the simple hypothesis $H_0: a = 2$ against the alternative simple hypotheses $H_1: a = 4$, a random sample of $X_1,X_2$ of size $n = 2$ will be used. Define the critical region to be $C = \{ (x_1,x_2): 9.5 <= x_1 + x_2 < \infty\}$. Calculate:

i) the significance level of the test, and
ii) the power of the test.

So to calculate the significance level i said $P(9.5 <= x_1 + x_2 < \infty |H_0 \text{ is true})$ but i'm not sure how to proceed from there and for ii) I have no clue.

Comment: It’s the probability you reject when $H_1$ holds (So the same thing as in part i, only assuming $H_1$.) You need to write down an integral that represents the probability and calculate it. (Or possibly calculate or look up what the pdf of the sum is. And then writing down the integral will be a little simpler.)

Comment: As $x_1$ and $x_2$ follows exponential distribution and are independent and I assume they are independent. Then, their sum follows gamma distribution with shape = 2 and scale = 2a.